# JAVA - Not able to properly fill multidimentional array from another array

Tags: java, jframe, jtable

I have a string of values separated by commas that I converted into an array, which I was then going to use to create a 2D array. When creating a loop to add the data from the first array to the 2D array it is repeating the data.

The output I'm getting is:

> 4428,40,401,610,2016,3821,31,347,572,2015,4381,38,341,520,2014,2536,17,193,290,2013,4295,39,371,552,2012,4643,45,343,502,2011,3922,28,312,475,2010,4434,30,350,541,2009,4038,28,341,536,2008,218,1,20,28,2007,46,0,6,15,2006,65,0,9,16,2005,4428,40,401,610,2016,3821,31,347,572,2015,4381,38,341,520,2014,2536,17,193,290,2013,4295,39,371,552,2012,4643,45,343,502,2011,3922,28,312,475,2010,4434,30,350,541,2009,4038,28,341,536,2008,218,1,20,28,2007,46,0,6,15,2006,65,0,9,16,2005,4428,40,401,610,2016,3821,31,347,572,2015,4381,38,341,520,2014,2536,17,193,290,2013,4295,39,371,552,2012,4643,45,343,502,2011,3922,28,312,475,2010,4434,30,350,541,2009,4038,28,341,536,2008,218,1,20,28,2007,46,0,6,15,2006,65,0,9,16,2005,4428,40,401,610,2016,3821,31,347,572,2015,4381,38,341,520,2014,2536,17,193,290,2013,4295,39,371,552,2012,4643,45,343,502,2011,3922,28,312,475,2010,4434,30,350,541,2009,4038,28,341,536,2008,218,1,20,28,2007,46,0,6,15,2006,65,0,9,16,2005,4428,40,401,610,2016,3821,31,347,572,2015,4381,38,341,520,2014,2536,17,193,290,2013,4295,39,371,552,2012,4643,45,343,502,2011,3922,28,312,475,2010,4434,30,350,541,2009,4038,28,341,536,2008,218,1,20,28,2007,46,0,6,15,2006,65,0,9,16,2005

and the correct output should be:

> 4428,40,401,610,2016,3821,31,347,572,2015,4381,38,341,520,2014,2536,17,193,290,2013,4295,39,371,552,2012,4643,45,343,502,2011,3922,28,312,475,2010,4434,30,350,541,2009,4038,28,341,536,2008,218,1,20,28,2007,46,0,6,15,2006,65,0,9,16,2005

Expected results:

> {{4428,40,401,610,2016}
>
> {3821,31,347,572,2015}
>
> {4381,38,341,520,2014}
>
> ...} and so on, every 5

My code for adding the array to the 2D array is below:

```
 {String[] columns = {"Yards","Touchdowns","Attempts","Incompletions","Year"};



String[] data1 = results1.split(",");

Object [][] data11 = new Object[columns.length][data1.length];
for(int i = 0; i<columns.length;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<data1.length;j++){
    data11[i][j] = data1[j];
    //System.out.print(data11[i][j]+",");
}
}}
```

EDIT: Solution!

```
Object [][] data11 = new Object[data1.length/columns.length][columns.length];
int column = -1;
for(int j = 0; j<data1.length;j++){
    if(j % columns.length == 0) column = column+1;
            data11[column][j % 5] = data1[j];
}
```

Comment: Can you please update your answer with a matrix representing the expected result? So we can understand how do you expect to pass from 1d array to matrix and know how to solve the problem.

Comment: @Joss Just updated with the matrix. The 5th number is always a year so it should go until 2005 which is the last year

Comment: I can't see where you are getting your numbers from. Please add the data1 variable to the code.

Comment: So, for what I understand your matrix should be of size [columns.length][data1.length / 5], isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this work for you:

```
Object [][] data11 = new Object[columns.length][data1.length / 5];
int column = -1;
for(int j = 0; j<data1.length;j++){
    if(j % 5 == 0) column = column + 1
    data11[j % 5][column] = data1[j];
}
```

Note the matrix size changed and the assignation too. Haven't tried, probably you can make a prettier version. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really close and it got me there! Just updated it with the solution that worked!

Answer (score 0):

You also loop the first array (i), so he will repeat it. Just write this:

```
 data11[0][j] = data1[j];
```

Or even don't do the first loop at all, depending on what you need.
Assuming your output, you only want to fill in the first position (0) of the array.

Comment: I was planning to then put the array into a JTable, but when i try to do that does not go to the next line, it just keeps the entire array on the first line with 4 empty rows below it. Also, in the output it has a bunch of null values inplace of where the wrong data was.

Comment: It's normal that you have duplicates. That's what your loop says.
So first you're gonna loop the columns array, and for each position in the columns array, you're gonna put a new array inside (data1). But you do this for every position of the columns array. So it's normal that you have duplicates. Can u maybe tell me your general goal? So I can try to find a better solution.